# QuillJS creates a new line in <pre> tags

Tags: javascript, angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am developing a little forum in Angular using QuillJS as the editor (https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill), and I want to add a "spoiler" to it. For now, I have a spoiler-component containing a button to hide/show some content in the view page, but I can't get it working in the editor.

I didn't succeed to add a button to hide/show some text in the editor, so I'm going for something like a code-block.
My problem is that I can't get it working as I want: I need to add a spoiler-component tag to my editor (it will not contain a button etc, but it's ok). I've inspected the already-implemented code-block, and when I succeed imitating it, it doesn't work as expected.

**Here is my last attempt to make it work:**

First, I need to pop a modal to ask for a spoiler title (text to be shown in the toggle button).

My Quill blot

```
import * as Quill from 'quill';

let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

class SpoilerComponent extends Block {
  static create(value) {
    let spoiler = document.createElement('spoiler-component');
    spoiler.setAttribute('title', value.getAttribute('title')); // my angular component has a "title" attribute
    spoiler.textContent = '...';
    let node = super.create(value);
    node.appendChild(spoiler);
    node.setAttribute('title', value.getAttribute('title'));
    return node;
  }
}
SpoilerComponent['blotName'] = 'spoiler-component'; 
SpoilerComponent['className'] = 'spoiler-component-container';
SpoilerComponent['tagName'] = 'pre';

Quill.register({
  'formats/spoiler-component': SpoilerComponent
});
```

My function to add a spoiler-component

```
const picker = this.dialog.open(SpoilerPickerComponent, { panelClass: 'spoiler-picker-box' });
    picker.afterClosed().subscribe(title => {
      let spoiler = document.createElement('spoiler-component');
      spoiler.setAttribute('title', title);
      this.quill.insertEmbed(this.index, 'spoiler-component', spoiler, 'user');
    });
```

The result of this

[image]

At each new line, it creates a new pre tag. But as the code-block, I want it to add a new line in the current spoiler-component, and to get out of it if there are more than 3 empty lines in a row.
Also, it's not containing any spoiler-component tags, as if my Quill blot was not working at all.
[image]

So is there a way to achieve my goal? Or is there a way to have something similar?

### Edit 1

I've made some progress (I guess ??).

I will get rid of the "pre" tag, as I realized I don't need it.

Here is my latest code :

```
import * as Quill from 'quill';
let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
class SpoilerComponent extends Block {
  static create(value) {
    console.log('value')
    let node = super.create(value);
    node.setAttribute('title', value.getAttribute('title'));
    return node;
  }
}
SpoilerComponent['blotName'] = 'spoiler-component'; 
SpoilerComponent['className'] = 'spoiler-component-container';
SpoilerComponent['tagName'] = 'spoiler-component';

Quill.register({
  'formats/spoiler-component': SpoilerComponent
});
```

And

```
const picker = this.dialog.open(SpoilerPickerComponent, { panelClass: 'spoiler-picker-box' });
    picker.afterClosed().subscribe(title => {
      let spoiler = document.createElement('spoiler-component');
      spoiler.setAttribute('title', title);
      this.quill.insertEmbed(this.index, 'spoiler-component', spoiler, 'user');
    });
```

The result is the following :

[image: img]

For the following HTML

[image: img]

The problem now is that :
When I press "enter", it creates a new empty spoiler-component ON THE SAME LINE.
When I press "enter" again, it creates a new empty spoiler-component on the line below...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you get the html result from Quill:

```
        html.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, '<br>')
            .replace(/<p>/g, '')
            .replace(/<\/p>/g, '<br>');
```

Got it from: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/357

Answer (score -1):

Although I do not have an answer to this specific question, you might want to check out TinyMCE. I have found TinyMCE to be a little more flexible than QuillJs in my experience. TinyMCE for angular: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular

Comment: Thank you, i will consider taking a look after trying a little more

Comment: I believe it is free because it is under the GNU GPL 2.1 license. The repository is on github https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce